# Where can I find a list of database design anti-patterns?

Tags: data-modeling

Is there any resource that I can find a compiled list of data modeling anti-patterns.

For quite some time I have been discussing matters like OTLT (or MUCK Tables) without knowing there is a name for it! I think knowing a list of anti-patterns would shorten or eliminate many database design debates.

Thank you,

Comment: You might try the [*SQL Antipatterns*](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557?ie=UTF8&keywords=sql%20antipatterns&qid=1465345830&ref_=sr_1_1&s=books&sr=1-1) book.

Comment: @Tim, please make your comment an answer, so I can mark it,thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the [SQL Antipatterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557) book.